# Where should I place my application wide UI customization

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subclass, appdelegate, uiappearance

I have a class that I have created to do all the work for customizing appearances. The class is `UIAppearance` delegate.

UI customization currently affects,

1. Navigation Bar
2. Search Bar
3. Tab bar

All these elements will not vary with `Views` as I can not forsee a situation where I might have different style for any of those.

**Where and How can I place it to be available application wide and such that I don't have to invoke those methods from everywhere (One time call to affect UI tweaks) ?**

- by subclassing ?
- is AppDelegate a good candidate for this ?
- importing the subject class and manually invoking the methods

**Is it possible to make one time calls for these customizations ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

UIKit classes like `UINavigationBar` give you an *appearance proxy* when you call `appearance` on the *class*:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];` sets `myColor` as the tintColor for all navigation bars.

See the [UIAppearance documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am using UIAppearance proxy. I have background images for all of them. can I really do them in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` ? That might take the **class in question** out of picture.

Comment: Yes, `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is the right place. You'd want this code to run exactly once each time the app is launched. Additionally, it is good to have all your appearance customization in one place.

Comment: What do you mean with class out of picture?

Comment: There will not be much point in having a class for few UI customization codes that are basically wrapped in few methods. And if it can be done from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, the class concept can be dropped. why not just have codes in there ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use singleTon class like SharedManager, Create all this object in it and it will be available through out your application.

//  Step 1: Create a file named "SharedManager.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SharedManager : NSObject
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *searchBar;

+(SharedManager *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

// step 2 : create a file : "SharedManager.m"

```
#import "SharedManager.h"

static SharedManager *_sharedManager;
@implementation SharedManager

@synthesize navBar , searchBar;

+(SharedManager *)sharedInstance
{
    if(_sharedManager == nil)
    {
        _sharedManager = [[SharedManager alloc] init];

        // Create Navigation Bar
        _sharedManager.navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

        // Create Search Bar
        _sharedManager.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedManager;
}

@end
```

//  To access the object use following code,
  #import "SharedManager.h"

```
 [[SharedManager sharedInstance].navBar];
```

it will return object of NavigationBar